# boost::variant and printing methods of elements in vector

Tags: c++, boost-variant

```
 std::vector< boost::variant<std::string, int> > vec;
 std::string s1("abacus");
 int i1 = 42;
 vec.push_back(s1);
 vec.push_back(i1);
 std::cout << vec.at(0).size() << "\n";
```

when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:68: error: ‘class boost::variant<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>’ has no member named ‘size’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

however, being a string it should have a size() method. I'm not sure what is going wrong. note that replacing the last line with:

```
std::cout << vec.at(0) << "\n";
```

will print "abacus", as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> being a string it should have a size() method

It’s not a `string` – it’s a `variant`. You first need to tell the compiler that you *know* there’s a `string` inside – i.e. retrieve it using `boost::get<std::string>(vec[0])`.

Be sure to read the [Boost.Variant tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the first type of this variant (which is the string), the class `boost::variant` which you are accessing with `vector::at()` has no method called `size()`, try something like::

```
boost::get<0>(vec.at(0)).size(); // I think that's the syntax....
```